# How to make reactjs website responsive using material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, grid-layout

I am working on reactjs project using material-ui. Web-page is working perfect on desktop layout but when I switch layout to responsive (mobile). Than all the text and images merge in eachother. My question is this that how can I make my site responsive. Below is the code snippet with its layout image.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  main: {
    width: "100%",
    minWidth: "100%",
  },
  grid1: {
    height: "100vh",
    minWidth: "100%",
    //backgroundImage: `url(${img1})`,
    backgroundColor: "khaki",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  img1: {
    backgroundSize: "contain",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    zIndex: "0",
    position: "relative",
    opacity: "0.7",
  },
  font1: {
    zIndex: "1",
    fontFamily: "Crimson-Text",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "350%",
    position: "absolute",
    left: "30%",
    top: "40%",
    color: "white",
  },
  font2: {
    zIndex: "1",
    fontFamily: "Crimson-Text",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "150%",
    position: "absolute",
    left: "40%",
    top: "53%",
    color: "white",
  },
  btn1: {
    zIndex: "1",
    fontFamily: "Crimson-Text",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    //fontSize: "150%",
    position: "absolute",
    left: "35%",
    bottom: "20%",
    color: "inherit",
    variant: "outlined",
    borderRadius: "1px",
    background: "white",
    "&:hover": { color: "inherit", variant: "contain", background: "grey" },
  },
  btn2: {
    zIndex: "1",
    fontFamily: "Crimson-Text",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    //fontSize: "150%",
    position: "absolute",
    left: "50%",
    bottom: "20%",
    color: "inherit",
    variant: "outlined",
    borderRadius: "1px",
    background: "white",
    "&:hover": { color: "inherit", variant: "contain", background: "grey" },
  },
}));

const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid container xs={12} sm={12}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} className={classes.grid1}>
        <img src={img1} className={classes.img1} alt="home1" />
        <Typography className={classes.font1}>Shoes made from wool</Typography>
        <Typography className={classes.font2}>Now in new colors</Typography>
        <Button className={classes.btn1}>Shop Men</Button>
        <Button className={classes.btn2}>Shop Women</Button>
      </Grid>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: You could use the grids and Hidden components they are great and please post the code in codesandbox if you want someone to edit your code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can change here:

```
main: {
    display:'flex',
    width: "100%",
    minWidth: "100%",
  },
```

and in the grid side:

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item item xs={12} sm={6} className={classes.grid1}>/*or you an use item xs={6} sm={3}*/
        <img src={img1} className={classes.img1} alt="home1" />
        <Typography className={classes.font1}>Shoes made from wool</Typography>
        <Typography className={classes.font2}>Now in new colors</Typography>
        <Button className={classes.btn1}>Shop Men</Button>
        <Button className={classes.btn2}>Shop Women</Button>
      </Grid>
```

for better understanding you should follow [that link](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#grid-with-breakpoints)

you can arrange your grid any way you want when you try to squeeze the browser. it will make it responsive for various size of screens